# Por que em nomes de arquivos e pastas, alguns caracteres ainda não são aceitos?

Tags: sistema-operacional, sistema-de-arquivos

Por que arquivos e pastas ainda não aceitam alguns caracteres diferentes?

[image: erro ao criar pasta com caracteres especiais]

Acredito que deve ter alguma influência programática para terem tomado essa decisão. Os Sistemas Operacionais tinham e/ou ainda têm restrições para que sejam produzidos dessa maneira?

Assim como os nomes de domínios que antigamente não aceitavam acentuação e caracteres diferentes, e passaram a trabalhar com eles, mais recentemente.

> An Internationalised Domain Name is a domain name that can contain
>   characters not defined by the ASCII standard. These characters include
>   most of the accented letters used in different European languages and
>   other characters that are not found in the Latin alphabet. (i.e
>   accentués.com)
>
> Technically, accented characters can not be used in DNS, which is why
>   every IDN is encoded as a string of non-accented character whose shape
>   is called ACE. In the latter, the domain names begin with XN - to
>   differentiate unaccented domain names. (i.e : xn--accentus-h1a.com)

(trecho retirado [daqui](http://www.netim.com/domain-name/accented-domains.html))

Exemplo:

The domain name ¥ƒΩ converted into ACE chain is xn--cba88bf7c

Nesse [artigo](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/) da w3 fala um pouco sobre essa "internacionalização" dos domínios

> User's expectations and use of the Internet have moved on since then,
>   and there is now a growing need to enable use of characters from any
>   language in Web addresses. A Web address in your own language and
>   alphabet is easier to create, memorize, transcribe, interpret, guess,
>   and relate to. It is also important for brand recognition. This, in
>   turn, is better for business, better for finding things, and better
>   for communicating. In short, better for the Web.

Acredito que essa pergunta tange mais sobre a historia da criação (logo tem um pouco a ver com programação) dos sistemas operacionais.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basicamente é um problema de ambiguidade em *parsing*. É um problema semelhante ao que temos em *strings* nas linguagens onde alguns caracteres são especiais, tais como a própria aspas, a barra invertida e a porcentagem ou chaves, etc.

Estes caracteres possuem um significado em comandos do sistema operacional, no caso o MS-DOS inicialmente e depois o Windows. Os Unixes possuem outro conjunto de caracteres que não podem ser usados.

Poderiam ter sido mais inteligentes e ter permitido esses caracteres dentro de aspas, e até ela poderia ser usada com um *escape*. Mas não fizeram. Também não é um grande problema. Provavelmente não mudam porque não é uma necessidade importante.

- `/` - indicador de *flag* do comando
- `\` - separador de pasta
- `:` - separador do volume
- `*` - coringa para indicar qualquer nome
- `?` - coringa para indicar qualquer caractere
- `"` - delimitador de textos (nomes que tem espaço precisam dele)
- `<` - direcionador de entrada
- `>` - direcionador de saída
- `|` - canalização da saída

Não tem a ver com acentuação, que é permitida.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Testando [AQUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXV8i.png) Ambiente Windows < Ambiente Linux >