# O caractere ponto e virgula (;) é permitido nos nomes de arquivos?

Tags: linux, windows, arquivo, sistema-de-arquivos, mac

O caractere "`;`" é permitido no nome de arquivos?
No windows pode-se usar o caractere "`;`" no nomeando de arquivos sem problema nenhum, porém não sei se a mesma regra serve para Mac ou Linux.
Pesquisei sobre nomeação de arquivos, e achei vários tópicos falando sobre outros caracteres, porém, não achei nada falando sobre "`;`".

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184020/por-que-em-nomes-de-arquivos-e-pastas-alguns-caracteres-ainda-n%c3%a3o-s%c3%a3o-aceitos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em princípio, pode, mas se for usar por linha de comando, precisa de "escape" ou aspas em Unix. Apesar de aceito no nome de arquivo, no Shell ele tem um significado especial, ele separa os comandos. No Windows é aceito sem restrições.

Como complemento, a Wikipedia em inglês tem um compêndio muito bom de informações sobre nomes de arquivo:

> [Artigo: **Filename**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename).

Em especial, traduzi esta tabela que lista os caracteres considerados especiais nos *filesystems* mais comuns (e outros nem tanto):

```
 /     barra            Usada como separador de caminho em sistemas Unix-like,
                        Windows e Amiga (a variável SwitchChar do DOS pode ser
                        setada para '/' e o COMMAND.COM considerará como indicador
                        de flag, mas o DOS e o Windows mesmos aceitam como
                        separador na API)

 \     barra invertida  Usada como separador padrão no DOS, OS/2 e Windows (mesmo
                        com SwitChar configurado para '-'; é aceito em nomes Unix)

 ?     interrogação     É usado como coringa em Unix, Windows, Amiga, e representa
                        um caractere único. É permitido em nomes Unix

 %     porcentagem      É um coringa em RT-11, define um caractere único. Em Windows
                        pode ser usado

 *     asterisco        Usado como coringa em Unix, DOS, RT-11, VMS e Windows.
                        Representa uma sequência de caracteres em Unix, Windows, DOS,
                        ou qualquer sequência na extensão (*.* significa "todos os
                        arquivos"). Em Unix, pode ser usado nos nomes de arquivo

 :     dois pontos      Serve para determinar o ponto de montagem no Windows, o
                        dispositivo virtual ou físico no Amiga, RT-11 e VMS e é o
                        separador de caminho no MacOS Clássico. No VMS, indica um
                        nome de nó DECnet quando usado em dobro (equivale a um endereço
                        NetBios. No Windows ainda é usado para separar um Data Stream
                        do nome de arquivo em NTFS

 |     barra vertical   Define um redirecionamento de software em Unix, DOS e Windows;
        ou pipe          Permitido em nomes Unix

 "     aspas duplas     Usadas para delimitar nomes com espaços em Windows

 <     menor que        Usado para redirecionar entrada, permitido em Unix

 >     maior que        Usado para redirecionar saída, permitido em Unix

 .     ponto            Permitido, mas a última ocorrência indica separador de extensão
                        em VMS, DOS, e Windows. Em outros sistemas, normalmente faz parte
                        do nome, e pode ter mais de uma ocorrência seguida. Normalmente, em
                        Unix indica que o nome deve ser escondido da listagem

       espaço           É permitido, mas como também é um separador de parâmetros de linha
                        de comando, deve-se delimitar o nome com aspas para diferenciar dos
                        parâmetros
```

Importante: em Unix, apesar de aceitos, os caracteres `<>|\:()&;#?*` normalmente precisam ser "escapados" com barra invertida, ou delimitados com aspas em linha de comando:

Ex: `five\ and\ six\<seven` ou mesmo `"five and six<seven"`.

### Considerações:

O simples fato de poder usar determinados caracteres não significa que você deve usá-los. A recomendação é de usar caracteres "menos comuns" somente onde houver uma razão que não pode ser contornada por outros meios, como normalização e sanitização.

Pensando em interoperabilidade, mesmo usando caracteres permitidos, a simples mistura de maiúsculas e minúsculas é um problema muito comum quando se trocam arquivos entre OSes diferentes, pois no Windows não há diferenciação, e em parde considerável dos outros OSes há. Como o uso de caracteres especiais também varia, evita-se muita dor de cabeça se limitando a uma nomenclatura simplificada (ficar na faixa `a-z0-9_.` por exemplo é uma boa pedida).

Acentuação e formatação fazem sentido para coisas manipuladas somente pelo usuário final (receita de bolo, carta de apresentação, planilha de prestações do financiamento da máquina de lavar, essas coisas), mas arquivos que devem ser processados por um sistema merecem um cuidado maior. Pessoalmente, acho um crime fazer como vejo muito aqui no site, de se fazer questão de manter nomes originais em upload de arquivo, quando seria muito mais simples armazenar os nomes no DB e simplesmente colocar uma string sequencial no filesystem.

Comment: Eu encontrei essa tabela em outros fóruns e como não havia nada falando ";" fiquei na duvida... Sua resposta com certeza sanou minha duvida, porém agora surgiu um problema para min... Estou salvando um arquivo de log com o seguinte formato "dia-mes-ano hora;minuto;segundo" sera que existe outra maneira "bonita" de salvar isso?

Comment: No mínimo inverter as posições, pq do jeito que vc exemplificou fica tudo fora de ordem. Eu costumo usar assim: `20180816_084117` sem muita frescura (ano, mes, dia, hora minuto segundo). Não precisa desprezar o usuário a ponto de achar que ele não vai entender. Se realmente quiser separar, pode fazer algo como `2018-08-16.08h42m31` ou mesmo `2018-08-16_08.42.31` - nessa ordem coisa de 2017 vai ficar com coisa de 2017, janeiro com janeiro, ordenado por dia. Se inverter as posições, vai ficar um de janeiro com um de fevereiro, depois volta pro dois de janeiro, e misturando o ano pra piorar.

Comment: Eu estava usando 2018-08-16 08;42;31 mas achei essa sua dica "2018-08-16.08h42m31" muito legal! Irei implementar logo logo. Mas uma duvida esse ponto '.' que tem ai não vai interferir em nada na extensão do arquivo né?

Comment: @EduardoMior o que define a extensão (que é uma coisa praticamente exclusiva de Windows, pois nos outros OSes nao quer dizer nada, é só parte do nome) é o último ponto. Um arquivo `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee`para o Windows é `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` com extensão `eee`. Se a extensão é importante, adicione uma depois da hora (até para o windows não esconder a hora no desktop). Exemplos: `2018-08-16.08h42m31.txt`, `2018-08-16.08h42m31.log`, etc

Comment: muito obrigado pela explicação, agora sim esta tudo resolvido.

Answer (score 3):

Nos dois casos, linux e mac, apenas os caracteres `/` e `\0` (null) são totalmente bloqueados, todos os outros podem ser usados, apesar de não recomendados.

Se você criar um arquivo com ponto e vírgula, ou outro caractere não convencional, você vai precisar de um `escape` para acessar o arquivo manualmente.

Exemplo:

```
Meu;arquivo.txt
```

Para ler:

```
cat Meu\;arquivo.txt
```

Mesmo permitindo quase todos os caracteres, para evitar problemas de acesso é recomendável usar apenas os seguintes:

- a-z
- A-Z
- 0-9
- underline (_)
- traço (-)
- ponto (.)

Outro exemplo mais extremo:

```
'"!@#$%&*()-_+=[{]}~^?;:><,..txt
```

Como acessar:

```
cat \'\"\!@#\$%\&\*\(\)-_+\=\[\{\]\}~\^\?\;\:\>\<\,..txt
```

Comment: Tanto sua resposta quanto a do Bacco resolveram meu questionamento porem agora tenho outro problema... estou salvando um arquivo de log com o seguinte formato "dia-mes-ano hora;minuto;segundo" sera que existe outra maneira "bonita" de