# Barras invertidas no caminho: elas influenciam em algo?

Tags: característica-linguagem, sistema-operacional, sistema-de-arquivos, path

Eu nunca entendi o porquê de alguns sistemas utilizarem a `\` e outros usarem a `/` para a mesma finalidade: dividir caminhos e endereços. Não existe um padrão de qual deve ser usada, ou pelo menos **não encontrei um**.

Enquanto programamos e definimos caminhos, qual destas barras devemos usar?

Tenho um exemplo que, em Laravel, ao chamar a função:

```php
$caminho = storage_path();
$caminhoConcatenado = $caminho . "/informacao/concatenada.txt";
```

No Windows, eu tenho o caminho:

```
$caminho = "C:\laragon\www\foo\bar\storage"
```

E no CentOS eu tenho:

```
$caminho = "/home/admin/web/quick_fox/lazy_dog/"
```

Quando concateno uma informação ao `$caminho`, eu não sei qual das barras usar. Se utilizo uma `/`, no CentOS ficará correto e legível, porém no Windows, eu terei aproximadamente isso:

```
$caminhoConcatenado = "C:\laragon\www\foo\bar\storage/informacao/concatenada.txt"
```

Nestas situações,

- o caminho é entendido corretamente?
- está correto realizar este tipo de operação?
- se não estiver correto, o que devo fazer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depende um pouco da linguagem, mas de forma geral não deveria lidar com *paths* por conta própria, as linguagens possuem biblioteca própria que sabe como lidar com isso e você trabalha com o caminho sem se preocupar com esse detalhe que é do sistema operacional. Em alguns casos se a linguagem não tem uma biblioteca padrão é possível usar alguma que lida com isto.

A maioria das pessoas faz errado ou usa uma linguagem que não fornece algo pronto e correto, o que não deixa de ser um erro do programar, aí a pessoa tem duas opções:

- fazer de um jeito e estabelecer que o código no roda na plataforma que o código foi pensado
- cuidar na mão para lidar com as diferenças de formato com um trabalho enorme e com potencial de fazer errado

Algumas linguagens possuem uma constante com o separador, o que ajuda um pouco generalizar o código, mas não torna completamente simples fazer certo. [Exemplo em PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php#constant.directory-separator).

Depende de onde vai usar o texto apresentado na pergunta. Aí ele é só um texto, para o sistema não é um *path*, só você lendo acha que é. É verdade que as APIs que acessam arquivos no sistema operacional costumam entender este texto, então pode ter uma API que entende isso perfeitamente e ter API que não entende, inclusive porque tem API que não lê só o *path*, lê outras coisas e a outra barra é usada para identificar alguma outra coisa e é algo válido no texto, aí fica ambíguo. Sem saber que API está usando não tem como afirmar se dá certo ou não. Essa característica não é da linguagem em si, no máximo do que a acompanha.

No PHP em geral aceita de qualquer jeito, mas não vou garantir que acontece sempre. Se qualquer forma a recomendação geral para PHP e outras linguagens é usar um padrão, e costuma ser mais adequado usar o padrão do Unix. Se alguma API não funcionar bem assim mesmo no Windows em geral consideramos ela uma API ruim e você terá que se virar.

Se quer saber sobre o uso dos caracteres já tem uma resposta sobre isto em [Por que em nomes de arquivos e pastas, alguns caracteres ainda não são aceitos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184020/101).

Answer (score 6):

Somente complementando a resposta do amigo com uma curiosidade, já que você disse que nunca entendeu o porquê de alguns sistemas utilizarem a barra `\` e outros usarem a `/` para a mesma finalidade.

Bom, o windows é o único que utiliza `\`, sistemas Unix e URLs utilizam `/`, isso se dá nos primórdios da Microsoft na época do MS-DOS 1.0.

Muitos dos utilitários do MS-DOS 1.0 foram escritos pela IBM, e eles utilizavam o `/` como switch character (um caractere que faz parte de um comando). Por exemplo no comando `dir /?` utilizamos `/?` para exibir a lista de ajuda do comando `dir` (em sistemas unix o switch character é o `-`).
Na época o fato do switch character da IBM `/` conflitar com o separador de diretórios de outro S.O. não fazia tanta importância para os desenvolvedores pois o DOS não trabalhava com diretórios, era somente arquivos em um diretório root.

Já no MS-DOS 2.0 eles implementaram o conceito de hierarquia, mas não podia utilizar o mesmo padrão do unix `/` pois este já era utilizado como switch character, também não poderiam utilizar o `.` pois este era utilizado para separar o nome dos arquivos das extenções, então a solução foi utilizar `\`.

E é por isso que a microsoft utiliza `\`.
Podemos conferir isso no blog do [Larry Osterman](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2005/06/24/why-is-the-dos-path-character/) da própria Microsoft.